# I want to limit the length of a string with 3 or 5, what's the regex should be

Tags: javascript, regex

Saying, I have a pattern.

```
const pattern = /^Idontknow$/;
```

I want to make this.

```
new RegExp(pattern).test('123'); // true
new RegExp(pattern).test('12345'); // true
new RegExp(pattern).test('1234'); // false
```

The first and second string length are 3 and 5, so they pass the test.
And the third is 4, so it can't pass.
Could anyone tell me how to write this pattern?

Comment: do you really need to use regex? because String.length would be much easier. `'123'.length == 3 || '123'.length == 5 // true`

Comment: why not just check string .length property?

Comment: /^[a-zA-Z]{5}$/ will check if you have exactly 5 letters in string. But you should use string.length instead of regex here.

Comment: `/^.{3}$|^.{5}$/`

Comment: you could do it like this : ^(?=[0-9]*$)(?:.{3}|.{5})$

Comment: Actually, I have more rules to validate, and I wanted to test with a single regex pattern. Finally, I used `.length` to validate its length, then used regex to validate other rules.

Comment: Just `/^\d{3}(?:\d{2})?$/` will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do in my opinion this would be to use `if (str.length == 3 || str.length == 5)`. Using regex to do this seems overly complicated and less readable.

Comment: With ES6 you can now also write `if ([3,5].includes(str.length)) ... `

Comment: @cars10m I considered that, however I imagine it's much less efficient to iterate through an array that just comparing them directly, and is less confusing/more readable anyways.

Comment: regex is much costlier